# Local Delta Lake instance with advanced features

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

Is it possible to deploy a Delta Lake instance locally (i.e., using delta-io) with the advanced features such as Z-ordering or Bloom filters?

As far as I have seen, most of these features are only available through Delta Lake on Databricks via the **dbr** cli. None of these features are mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/) of the OSS version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible - these features are Databricks only as of right now.

Update on 03.02.2022: [Just published roadmap for H1 2022](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/920) includes implementation of some of the advanced features into the open source version

Update July 2022: [Delta 2.0.0](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/tag/v2.0.0) includes most of the advanced features.